# How to get same Columns from different tables

Tags: nhibernate

I have 3 tables

> task (Id,text,Contact_Id)
>   users(Id,name)
>   company(id,name)

and 2 junction tables

> task_users (task_id,user_id)
>   task_companies (task_id,company_id)

note: contact_id may be refer to users table or company

How can I get `task id, task text, contact name` in one Criteria

Comment: do you have the tables mapped to corresponding objects? can we see the mapping between them?

Answer (score 0):

This's example with QueryOver, but it almost like ICriteria.

```
Contact contact = null;
mappingSession.QueryOver<Task>()
   .JoinAlias(() => task.Contact, () => contact)
   .SelectList(list => list
     .SelectGroup(task => task.Id)
     .Select(task => task.Text)
     .Select(() => contact.Name))
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
   .List();
```

Other is a mapping. You can make base entity "Contact" and extend from it User and Company.